Global Convergence for Newton's Method under sign change of $f'''$
I am trying to answer the following question from a past exam to help me study for a future exam:
"Show that in $d=1$, Newton's method to minimize a function $f$ with a unique minimum at $x_0$ converges if $f(x)\in C^3(\mathbb{R}), f''(x_0)\ge \delta>0, f'''(x)>0$ for $x>x_0$ and $f'''(x)<0$ for $x<x_0$."
I know how to prove this without the assumption on $f'''(x)$ changing sign at $x_0$ while additionally assuming that $x\in B(x_0, \epsilon)$ for small enough $\epsilon>0$. In this case, Newton's method is, with initial value $x^{(0)}$,
$$x^{(k+1)}=\phi(x^{(k)}), \quad \phi(x)=x-\frac{f'(x)}{f''(x)}.$$
We notice that
$$\phi'(x)= \frac{f'(x) f'''(x)}{(f''(x))^2}$$
and since $f'(x_0)=0$ and $f''(x_0)\ge \delta$, we can make $|\phi'(x)|\le K$ for some $0<K<1$ if we take $|x^{(0)}-x_0|<\epsilon$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$. Since $\phi(x_0)=x_0$, we can take $\epsilon$ again smaller if necessary so that $\phi:\overline{B(x_0, \epsilon)} \to \overline{B(x_0, \epsilon)}$. Then, a standard contraction argument proves convergence.
However, if we remove the condition on $x^{(0)}$ and add this sign change condition on $f'''(x)$, how are we able to prove convergence for any initial value?
Unless the question is wrong and this is not possible of course.

This is pure geometry. Switch the mental frame to the root $x_0$ of $g=f'$. Then the assumptions say that $g$ is strictly growing, switching from being concave left of the root $x_0$ to convex right of the root.
The Newton step is finding the roots of the tangents of $g$. Due to the convexity right of $x_0$, the tangent there are also supporting lines, the root of each single tangent will fall right of $x_0$ but closer to it. For the concave region left of $x_0$ a similar argument applies.
This process can only converge to a root, and as there is only one of them, convergence to $x_0$ is assured. This obviously up to this point makes no statement about the speed of convergence. The quadratic convergence is a local property that is established as you already presented.

Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to show also show this algebraically?
